# ckeditor source view formatting lost?

Tags: ckeditor, wysiwyg

I've just upgraded from CKEditor 4.4.4 to CKEditor 4.5.2 and it seems that the source code formatting is lost. This is also the case with all demos on the official case eg. [main demo page](http://ckeditor.com/demo).

It used to look like this (nice formatting, coloring):
[image: CKEditor 4.4.4]

And now it looks like this:
[image: CKEditor 4.5.2]

**Does anybody know if I need a plugin or if it's a bug?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CKEditor has never provided syntax coloring in source mode.

Previously you have used some third party plugin, so you must add it again.

Comment: I checked the config files and found no difference. But after adding codemirror to the new version it worked like expected.